# cmake ExternalProject cache overwritten

Tags: cmake

Hello I'm facing a problem regarding CMake and External Projects.

I set a compiler and some flags via `CMAKE_CACHE_ARGS` and/or `CMAKE_ARGS` this works the first time I run `make` but on any subsequent call the CMake Cache of the external project is rebuild (deleted) and the flags are not set accordingly to the flags I specified! So I wonder is there any workaround/way to specify the compiler only once to prevent rebuilding of the cache?

Following is a very basic test project which downloads and compiles GTest, first call to `make` compiles with Clang++ and the given flags, any following call to make will cause the CMake Cache to be rebuild without the proper flags being set!

```
cmake_minimum_version_required(VERSION 2.8.6)
project(test)

include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(
    GTest
    SVN_REPOSITORY http://googletest.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release-1.7.0/
    CMAKE_ARGS
    -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:STRING=clang++
    -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:STRING="\"-std=c++1y -stdlib=libc++\""
    INSTALL_COMMAND "" # One can not install GTest so dont do anything here
    LOG_DOWNLOAD 1
    LOG_UPDATE 1
    LOG_CONFIGURE 1
    LOG_BUILD 1
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but with a different setup. Although this answer does not seem to apply to your setup it might be helpful for someone else.

In my case the issue was declaring the project with:

```
project(test LANGUAGES C)
```

The external project was a C++ project. Adding `CXX` to languages (or removing the option altogether, since `C CXX` is the default) solved the problem for me.